# How can I insert rich snippets (data highlighter) to my Blogger template manually?

Tags: blogger, rich-snippets

I would like to insert the codes of schema.org/Article to my posts on Blogger. I already tried https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/ but it just didn't show my blog so I wasn't able to highlight the data... is there any tutorial that I can use to accomplish this? can anybody guide me to do so? I would really appreciate your help... Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. I've tried it on schema.org [blog's page](http://blog.schema.org/2013/06/schemaorg-and-json-ld.html) and it works fine. And as I see Blogger allows you to make posts in html mode.

If Markup Tool still doesn't work you can do it by hand. Microdata is rather simple and schema.org site itself provides some examples. E.g. for [article](http://schema.org/Article)

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <span itemprop="name">How to Tie a Reef Knot</span>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>     
</div>
```

After markup injection you can check it using [Yandex's](http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml) or [Google's](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) validators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would it be for rating starts (5 yellow starts that appear on SERP)? should the changes be made on every post or template? If I give you my template could you please do it for me? I don't know pretty much about coding :S

Comment: You're welcome! For rating use http://schema.org/Review (there are good examples below the page). You should change template if you'd like to have it on every page. Otherwise you can do it just for several posts. I'm not ready to help you with template, sorry.